# Ansible extract value from JSON output and use it in another tasks

Tags: json, ansible, uri, ansible-2.x

Using the below task I want to extract the `authresponse` signature value:

```
- uri:
   url: "http://10.25.155.x/axapi/v3/auth"
   method: POST
   validate_certs: no
   follow_redirects: all
   body: { "credentials": { "username": "admin","password": "a10" } } 
   return_content: yes
   body_format: json
  register: "a10"
```

Output:

```
"json": {
    "authresponse": {
        "description": "the signature should be set in Authorization header for following request.", 
        "signature": "6123befcb272ae2d0a9b92f1842dba"
    }
},
```

I have to pass the signature value to the below task in `Authorization`:

```
- name: access list
  uri:
    url: "http://10.25.155.x/axapi/v3/access-list/extended/"
    method: POST
    headers:
       Content-Type: "application/json"
       Authorization: A10 6123befcb272ae2d0a9b92f1842dba
    body: { "extended": { "extd": 102, "rules": [ { "extd-seq-num": 15,"extd-action": "permit","tcp": 1,"src-any": 1,"dst-host": "172.69.4.4","dst-eq" : 443 } ] } }
    validate_certs: no
    follow_redirects: all
  with_items: "{{a10.results}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to refer to the specific key from the data structure you registered in the first task. The JSON is already mapped into an Ansible (Python) object:

```
Authorization: "A10 {{ A10.json.authresponse.signature }}"
```